# Reason for sudden inability to SSH into GCP VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine

I was no longer able to SSH into a Google Cloud Compute Engine VM instance that previously showed no problems.
The error logs show the following

> @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Struct" value: {
> conditionNotMet: { userVisibleMessage: "Supplied fingerprint does not
> match current metadata fingerprint."

Trying SSH through the console showed

> Code: 4003 Reason: failed to connect to backend Please ensure that:
>
> - your user account has iap.tunnelInstances.accessViaIAP permission
> - VM has a firewall rule that allows TCP ingress traffic from the IP range XXX.0/20, port: 22
> - you can make a proper https connection to the IAP for TCP hostname: https://tunnel.cloudproxy.app You may be able to connect without using
>   the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.

The VM instance logs showed the following

> Error watching metadata: Get
> http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1//?recursive=true&alt=json&wait_for_change=true&timeout_sec=60&last_etag=XXX:
> net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
> headers)

After stopping and restarting the instance I was able to ssh again but I would like to understand the reason for the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received indicates that the [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/setCommonInstanceMetadata?hl=en) server's response caused the connection to the Google Compute Engine VM instance to time out. This could be because the server was taking too long to respond or there was a problem with the network. You can try to resolve this issue by either increasing the timeout value by using this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/general-tips#idle-connections) or waiting for the instance to become healthy using the gcloud compute wait command.

The instance was unable to reach the metadata server, as suggested by the [timeout error message](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors#failed_to_connect_to_backend). This could be a problem with the instance itself or with the network connection. A firewall or network configuration issue could have prevented the instance from connecting to the metadata server, or an issue with the underlying infrastructure could have rendered the instance temporarily unavailable.

To prevent this issue from happening again, you can increase the timeout value or use the gcloud compute wait command to wait for the instance to become healthy.it is recommended that you regularly update the SSH key used to connect to the instance, and check that the instance can reach the metadata server by making an HTTPS request to the IAP for TCP hostname. Additionally, it is important to ensure that your user account has the "iap.tunnelInstances.accessViaIAP" permission, and that the VM has a firewall rule that allows TCP ingress traffic from the IP range XXX.0/20, port: 22.

If you are using windows vm try troubleshooting steps mentioned in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors#reset_ssh_metadata).